# PHP Mongo Pull issue "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using mongodb & want to remove a subdocument using pull.

```
"_id":{"$oid":"6285eddb143ac418a7641872"},
"invoice_id":12121212,
"users":{"73":"2020-05-25 15:43:27","224":"","2260":"","47":"2022-02-21 17:26:00"},
```

I am trying to remove "47":"2022-02-21 17:26:00" from "users" subdocument using Pull method

```
$data = array("users.47"=>"2022-02-21 17:26:00");

[$pull] => Array
        (
            [users.47] => 2022-02-21 17:26:00
        )
```

I am Getting Error :- "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"

Anyone  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$pull` is not suitable in your scenario as `users` is not an array.

You need the [`$unset`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $unset: {
    "users.47": ""
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q5B5R8UKoEM)